# javascript in svg doesn't work when svg is imported as an image in markdown

Tags: javascript, svg, markdown

I was trying to make an SVG returning a variety of shapes by recognizing the image to render from the URL Parameters. It was working well when I ran the SVG file on chrome, but when I used it as an image in my markdown file, it doesn't work.
My SVG code looks like this :

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <script>
      const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
      const shape = params.get('shape');
      document.documentElement.style.width=document.documentElement.style.height=(params.get('strokeWidth')? 
      Number(params.get('strokeWidth')):0)+100+'px';
      if(shape === 'rect'){
        const rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
        rect.setAttribute('style', `
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        fill: ${params.get('fill') || 'transparent'};
        stroke: ${params.get('stroke') || 'black'};
        stroke-width: ${params.get('strokeWidth') || '5'}px;
      `)
      document.documentElement.prepend(rect);
    }
  </script>
</svg>
```

and my markdown looks like this :

```html
<embed src="shapes.svg?shape=rect" type='image/svg+xml'>
```

It doesn't show anything when imported.
So, is there any way to do this?

Comment: documentElement is your HTML document: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/svg-document-documentelement-property/

Comment: Hey @Danny, thanks for your comment, but my svg code is in the shapes.svg file, that's why the 'documentElement' means the main svg element, and not the html element. Therefore, it's not the problem. I've also tried it by debugging. The main question is to embed svg into markdown without losing interactivity. Kindly, read the problem again and help me if possible. Thanks again!